# How secure is PHP session_start $_SESSION value as login verification?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

If a user successfully logs in and passes security checks (username, password, 2fa... whatever) and the hypothetical PHP login system then does something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in_userid'] = 1;
```

How safe is it to then rely on the existence of that $_SESSION value 'logged_in_userid' as proof that this person really did actually previously pass the full security check? Not very, I'm thinking.

If by XSS someone was to determine the PHPSESSID, and manually add that to their own local cookies. Are they not then going to be automatically assumed to be logged in when they visit the same system?

If so - would a resolution be to record, at login time, also in the _SESSION the: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_USER_AGENT and X_FORWARDED_FOR and compare at each request time not only the _SESSION logged_in_userid but also the _SESSION REMOTE_ADDR etc etc with those found in the current _SERVER vars?

Or is that flawed also?

Answer (score 2):

It actually is secure **but** you need to do some extra stuff to make sure that someone can't 'hijack' the session by XSS for example as you mentioned:

```
static protected function preventHijacking()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['IPaddress']) || !isset($_SESSION['userAgent']))
        return false;

    if ($_SESSION['IPaddress'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        return false;

    if( $_SESSION['userAgent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The function above checks the IP address  to see if it's with the original user and not by someone else.

Comment: Thank you. That's much the same as I have coded but you've additionally checked for 'isset'. I've now added that and also added a check for them being set, but being set with a blank value. I wondered about setting a cookie and a session variable with the time of login, to also be compared in some way - but I guess in fact that's just the same as a matching session cookie so no benefit to security.

Comment: PS. Your code does not check the X_FORWARDED_FOR value for a match which is important for a lot of people as more and more sites are behind services like CloudFlare which mean _all_ visitor's REMOTE_ADDR values can be the same.

Comment: How about this though... on each access of the secure system, set a cookie with the current time, a session value with the current time... and before doing so compare the last modified time of the session file in the php system. On next access the three should be identical and would be extremely hard to spoof. eg: $session_time = filemtime(session_save_path()."/sess_".session_id()); $_SESSION['t'] = $now; setcookie('t', $now);

Comment: Alternative? I'm doing all!

Answer (score -1):

OWASP has a great guideline how to handle session management (and authentication). In practice you'll have to store a session ID at the client and verify the session every request:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

What you are talking about is also covered in the: session fixation